# Conditionally Filtered Autocomplete Script based on another Column in a Form (SPO)

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, filter, list-form, conditional

I am using the script below to autopopulate a text column called 'RelatedPeople' (Both Internal and External Column Name). The script pulls from the 'Title' Column of the 'People' List. I was wondering if this script could be ammended so that it ONLY showed items from the People List based on a matching value in another column in the same form.

**EXAMPLE**

1. *Company Name*: Fed-Ex
2. *RelatedPeople*: (autopopulate would ONLY render items in the 'People' List who had 'Fed-Ex' in 'RelatedCompany' column -- or were previously associated with 'Fed-Ex'

Basically, this would allow someone to choose from a list of 10-15 items instead of 2000 items.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
    sourceList: "People",
    sourceColumn: "Title",
    columnName: "RelatedPeople",
    filterType: "Contains",
    ignoreCase: true,
    numChars: 3,
    slideDownSpeed: 'normal'
    });
    });
```